# how to remove the empty quotes from the list using python?

Tags: python, list, tokenize

I have a python script that pre-processes the text before I can make the text analysis. Some of the functions to clean the text are:

- to remove strings that are less than two characters.
- to tokenize the text

The problem is that the first function returns a list and the second takes the returned list and also returns a list so it becomes list inside list. Like this:

```
['[', "'الموضوع", "'", ',', "'إجتماع", "'", ',', "'بين", "'", ',',
"'الجنة", "'", ',', "'البحرية", "'", ',', "'الفرعية", "'", ',',]']
```

where the result must be like this :

```
['الموضوع', 'إجتماع', 'بين', 'الجنة', 'البحرية', 'الفرعية',]
```

the returned result of the remove stop word :

```
['ا', 'ل', 'م', 'و', 'ض', 'و', 'ع', ' ', 'إ', 'ج', 'ت', 'م', 'ا', 'ع', ' ', 'ب', 'ي', 'ن', ' ', 'ا', 'ل', 'ج', 'ن', 'ة', ' ', 'ا', 'ل', 'ب', 'ح', 'ر', 'ي', 'ة', ' ', 'ا', 'ل', 'ف', 'ر', 'ع', 'ي', 'ة', ' ', 'و', 'ن', 'ظ', 'ي', 'ر', 'ت', 'ه', 'ا', ' ', 'ف', 'ي', ' ', 'م', 'ب', 'س', 'و', 'ط', ' ', 'ا', 'ل', 'م', 'س', 'ت', 'ن', 'د', ' ', 'ب', 'ر', 'ق', 'ي', 'ة', ' ', 'ر', 'ق', 'م', ' ', '1', '7', '1', 'ع', ' ', 'ت', 'ا', 'ر', 'ي', 'خ', ' ', '1', '2', '1', ]
```

where the result must be:

```
['تاريخ', '1212019','الموضوع', 'إجتماع', 'بين', 'الجنة', 'البحرية', 'الفرعية',]
```

## code

```
def remove_1char(text):
    tokens = text.split()
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if len(word) > 1]   
    result = str(tokens)
    write_file("remove_1char.txt",result)
    return result

def tokenize_text(text):
    tokens=word_tokenize(text)
    write_file("tokenize_text.txt",tokens)
    return tokens



 def remove_stopwords(tokens):
       write_file("tokens_before_remove.txt",tokens)
       stop_word_list = set(stopwords.words('arabic'))
       clean_tokens= [tok for tok in tokens if tok not in stop_word_list]
       write_file("remove_stop_word.txt",clean_tokens)
       return clean_tokens

def clean_text(text):
    rmws = remove_whiteSpace(text)
    rmp = remove_punctuations(rmws)
    rmd = remove_diacritics(rmp)
    rmrc = remove_repeating_char(rmd)
    rm1c = remove_1char(rmrc)
    clean_tokens = remove_stopwords(rm1c)
    write_file("result.txt",clean_tokens)
    return clean_tokens
```

So how to fix this problem?

Comment: `result = str(tokens)` does not what you think it does - it returns the string representation of the list. If you want a string, just use something like `' '.join(tokens)`. Also, you don't really show how you call the functions.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen your comment work thank you make an answer to upvote ...
but now i have an error in the remove stop word also it return a false answer.

can you help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are doing, and what is the problem - can you edit the question to make this more clear?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Let's open a Python REPL and go through your code.

I assume the first line specifies the input string, to assign it to a variable.

```py
>>> l = ['الموضوع', 'إجتماع', 'بين', 'الجنة', 'البحرية', 'الفرعية',]
>>> l
['الموضوع', 'إجتماع', 'بين', 'الجنة', 'البحرية', 'الفرعية']
```

You didn't specify which function is called, but I assume you first call the function `remove_1char` for each input string. We will call the lines of the function one after another an view the results for the first item of the list, which we will call `text`.

```py
>>> text = l[0]
>>> tokens = text.split()
>>> tokens
>>> ['الموضوع']
```

Since every word in the input sequence consists of one word, the output is as expected.

```py
>>> tokens = [word for word in tokens if len(word) > 1]
>>> tokens
['الموضوع']
```

And all words have more then 1 character. Also as expected.

```py
>>> result = str(tokens)
>>> result
"['الموضوع']"
>>>
```

In this line the string representation of the list is assigned to result. That's probably not what you want. I think you want to connect the tokens to a single string. This can be done with the `join` function.

```py
>>> result = ' '.join(tokens)
>>> result
'الموضوع'
>>>
```

Comment: yes i solved this problem now i have a second one if you see my updated question .thank you.

Comment: @DevDj StackOverflow is not intendeed to edit the question for each new problem you experienced. Instead a question should work as a knowledge source for other people, so each question should focus on one specific problem. If you have another question please create a new question for it.